# storing and printing out elements of structs in C

Tags: c, struct

I have created a simple struct:

```
struct album {
    char title[20];
    char artist[20];
};
```

and later in the program I created an instance `a` (`struct album a;`). I only need to ask the user to enter the title and the artist so that I save them in the appropriate place and then print the values:

```
printf("Please enter your album: \n");
printf("album name: ");
scanf("%.20s", a.title);

fflush(stdin);
printf("artist: ");
scanf("%.20s", a.artist);

printf("======\n");
printf("The album's name is %s and the artist is %s\n", a.title, a.artist);
```

however when I run this, I get this result:

[image]

Part of the input text is lost. What exactly goes wrong here?

Comment: Ah, that sucks. Actually I am reading from a book that hasn't yet introduced `fgets`. Now I realize why `scanf` is not that popular.

Comment: For new learners of C, my standing answer is *never* use `scanf()`. I don't understand why so many C books and courses pair it with `printf()` when it has so many pitfalls and traps. As a 30+ year user of C, I avoid `scanf()` entirely. If I need its conversions, I use `fgets()` to fill buffers, and as a last resort only, `sscanf()` to convert fields.

Comment: Hey, kudos on using the width specifier in the format string! But it should be `%.19s` - the last element is where `\0` goes.

Comment: %s only reads up to a space character, so that's the reason you get only the first word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `%s` specifier in scanf, the length specifier is the *number of characters to write*. This differs from most functions which expect the size of the entire buffer.

Since your buffer needs to contain the null terminator, you need to be using `"%.19s"` here. Another option is to not hardcode the value:

```
scanf("%.*s", (int)sizeof a.title - 1, a.title);
```

Note that this only works if `a.title` is an array (not a pointer), and the cast is necessary because `int` may be a smaller type than `size_t` but the `*` expects `int`.

As noted by others, `%s` is for reading up until the next whitespace. You can read up until the next line with `%[` , for example:

```
scanf("%.19[^\n]", a.title);
```

The `^` means to keep reading until any of the following characters are hit, and `\n` actually means the newline specifically, not general whitespace.

You will want to flush the buffer after doing this, because the newline will still be in the buffer. However `fflush(stdin);` is not portable. The portable way to discard the rest of the current line is:

```
int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' ) { }
```

Answer (score 4):

scanf reads characters up to white space. So if you are entering Michel Jackson the space in between Michel and Jackson terminates your string so you only get the string Michel.

Try using something like fgets:

```
fgets(a.artist, 20, stdin);
```

fgets gets terminates the string on new line rather than white space.

**if you do use fgets make sure to remove the new line character from the end of the string of you do not want a new line character at the end.